# LOGIN CON REGISTRO DE INFORMACIÓN PHP

Tags: php, mysql, php7, php5

Tengo un sistema básico para CONDUCTORES DE VIAJES INTERPROVINCIALES, donde el conductor inicia sesión, luego registra el viaje que va a recorrer y todo debe estar guardado en la base de datos **PERO POR ALGUN MOTIVO NO INSERTA LA INFORMACIPON DEL VIAJE EN LA TABLA viajes** (POSIBLE ERROR EN insertar_viaje.php) comparto todo:

TABLAS: solo los PK son INT los demas atributos son varchar(100) para ambas tablas.

-**LOGIN DEL CONDUCTOR** (ID (PK Autoincrementable),DNI,NICK,PASS).

-**VIAJES** (ID (PK) Autoincrementable),TIPO,PARTIDA,LLEGADA,HORA_PARTIDA,HORA_LLEGADA,PASAJEROS,DNI_CONDUCTOR).

**EL LOGIN**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>LOGIN CONDUCTOR</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="validar.php" method="post">
        <h1>LOGIN DE PRUEBA</h1>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="USUARIO">
        <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="CONTRASEÑA">
        <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**VALIDACIÓN BASICA ("validar.php"):**

```
<?php 
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$contrasena=$_POST['contrasena'];

$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","proyecto");

session_start();
$_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
$_SESSION['contrasena']=$contrasena;

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE NICK='$usuario'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con,$consulta);

if ($resultado) {
    # code...
    header("location:viajes.php");
    }
?>
```

**DOCUMENTO ("viajes.php")**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$usuario=$_SESSION['usuario'];

$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","proyecto");

$consulta = "SELECT DNI FROM LOGIN WHERE NICK='$usuario'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con,$consulta);

$filas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    $dni_x = $filas['DNI'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>.:Registra tu viaje:.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>REGISTRA TU VIAJE</h1>
        <form action="insertar_viaje.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="dni_conductor" value="<?php echo $dni_x ?>">
            <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="Ida y Vuelta" required>Ida y Vuelta</input>
            <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="Solo Ida" required>Solo Ida</input>
            <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="Multiples destinos" required>Multiples destinos</input>
            <select name="partida">
                <option value="default" >&ndash; Punto de Partida &ndash;</option>
                <option>Ayna - San Francisco</option>
            </select>
            <select name="llegada">
                <option value="default">&ndash; Punto de Llegada &ndash;</option>
                <option>Ayacucho</option>
            </select>
            <select name="hora_partida">
                <option value="default">&ndash; Horario de Salida &ndash;</option>
                <option>08:00:00</option>
            </select>
            <select name="hora_llegada">
                <option value="default">&ndash; Horario de Retorno &ndash;</option>
                <option>05:00:00</option>
            </select>
            <select name="pasajeros">
                <option value="default">&ndash; Cantidad de Pasajeros &ndash;</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5 a más</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**DOCUMENTO ("insertar_viaje.php")**

```
<?php 
    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","proyecto");

    if (isset($_POST['guardar'])) {
        $dni_conductor = $_POST['dni_conductor'];
        $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
        $partida = $_POST['partida'];
        $llegada = $_POST['llegada'];
        $hora_partida = $_POST['hora_partida'];
        $hora_llegada = $_POST['hora_llegada'];
        $pasajeros = $_POST['pasajeros'];

        $consultax = "INSERT INTO VIAJES(ID, TIPO, PARTIDA, LLEGADA, HORA_PARTIDA, HORA_LLEGADA, PASAJEROS, DNI_CONDUCTOR) VALUES 
        (NULL,'$tipo','$partida','$llegada','$hora_partida','$hora_llegada','$pasajeros','esta bien')";

        $resultadox = mysqli_query($con,$consultax);
        if ($resultadox)
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("SE GUARDO EL REGISTRO CORRECTAMENTE!") </script>'
        }else{
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("REGISTRO INCORRECTO... INTENTALO NUEVAMENTE!") </script>';
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask]. ¿Qué versión de php realmente estás utilizando? Y ¿cuál es el _posible_ error que mencionas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$consultax = "INSERT INTO VIAJES(ID, TIPO, PARTIDA, LLEGADA, HORA_PARTIDA, HORA_LLEGADA, PASAJEROS, DNI_CONDUCTOR) VALUES       (NULL,'".$tipo."','".$partida."','".$llegada."','".$hora_partida."','".$hora_llegada."','".$pasajeros."','esta bien')";
```

debes corregir tu string de la consulta

Answer (score 0):

Al ser tu id autoincrementale no es necesario que lo especifiques al hacer la consulta.

`$consultax = "INSERT INTO VIAJES(TIPO, PARTIDA, LLEGADA, HORA_PARTIDA, HORA_LLEGADA, PASAJEROS, DNI_CONDUCTOR) VALUES ('$tipo','$partida','$llegada','$hora_partida','$hora_llegada','$pasajeros','esta bien')";`